# Hair / Fur texture too dark after being baked - version 3.5.1

Tags: texture-baking, hair

I hope someone can help me with this but when I try to bake my hair particles (that have been converted to a mesh) diffuse texture to another mesh, it comes out too dark even though it looks ok in render view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please tell us how you baked it. Have you checked the light options in the bake settings? Have you turned off all lights in the scene and used a bright world color while baking?